# Calling Route.modelFor on a parent Route with multiple models in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I have a parent route (defined below) that attempts to return multiple models and is based on this discussion: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/loading-multiple-models-in-a-single-route/5794/15

```
App.PropertyPricingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            property: this.store.find('property', { propertyId: params.propertyId }),
            rooms: this.store.find('roomType', { propertyId: params.propertyId })
        });
    }
});
```

Then in a child route, I call `modelFor()` on the parent route, and try to access one of the two models. See below:

```
App.PropertyPricingUpchargesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        var propertyId = this.modelFor('propertyPricing').property.get('id');
        return this.store.find('upcharge', { propertyId: propertyId });
    }
}
```

The problem is that `propertyId` reports as `undefined` because `this.modelFor('propertyPricing').property instanceof App.Property` returns `false`, meaning I can't `get` a property off of it as expected.

Not sure where things are going wrong here, or if there's a better practice for what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call find by query (which is find with an object as the parameter), Ember Data isn't sure how many results or if any will be returned, so it returns a collection.  Usually if you are finding a particular record it would be `this.find('property', params.propertyId)`.

With your current code though, assuming you are guaranteed to get a result back and it's just one you would need to grab the first record from the collection in order to get that id.

```
App.PropertyPricingUpchargesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        var propertyId = this.modelFor('propertyPricing').get('property.firstObject.id');
        return this.store.find('upcharge', { propertyId: propertyId });
    }
}
```